# Admob Native ads crashing when clicked in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, native-ads

I have an activity showing recyclerView along with Native Admob ads. The ads are loading and everything is working perfect but when someone clicks on the ad, the app gets crashed. Also the crash does not happen everytime but around every 5 times out of 10.

Here's the log:

```
                                                                      Process: aculix.com.rakshabandhan, PID: 16098
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                          at aculix.com.rakshabandhan.Fragments.OneFragment$2.onItemClick(OneFragment.java:133)
                                                                          at aculix.com.rakshabandhan.RecyclerItemClickListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerItemClickListener.java:36)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouchIntercept(RecyclerView.java:2628)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2674)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2175)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2632)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2321)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:416)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1808)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:3065)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:71)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(DecorView.java:378)
                                                                          at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:10244)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4444)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4312)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4005)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4062)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3912)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3878)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3886)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3859)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6253)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6227)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6188)
                                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6356)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
```

Comment: some error logs might help to understand your problem better

Comment: try to catch your error and resolve that.

Comment: post your `aculix.com.rakshabandhan.Fragments.OneFragment$2.onItemClick` code

Comment: it seems something is not initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. For handling the clicks, I was using another class as shown below.

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
}

GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
    View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}}
```

And then in the fragment, I was setting up the click listener as below

```
  recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {
                    // TODO Handle item click



                }
            })
    );
```

Now I am handling the click listener inside the Adapter as shown below and it is working perfectly.

```
 myViewHolder.rInfo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    }
            });
```